# Can't deserialize json with jackson in kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, jackson

I've got a data class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class RouteDetails(
    val name: String,
    val boundingBox: JsonNode,
    val coursePoints: JsonNode
)
```

That I would like to deserialize a big json payload into (example is abbreviated):

```
{
  "type": "route",
  "route": {
    "id": 40307258,
    "name": "some bike route",
    "bounding_box": [
      {
        "lat": 3
        "lng": -9
      },
      {
        "lat": 3,
        "lng": -9
      }
    ],
    "course_points": [
      {...}
    ]
  }
}
```

And it seems like this should be a straight forward deserialization from what I can tell:

```
val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
return objectMapper.readValue(response, RouteDetails::class.java)
```

But when I actually try this I get an error:
[image: error]

> cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

I've looked up examples and the documentation and I can't tell what I'm doing wrong. I have a data class, I have the annotation to ignore the properties. Not seeing what I'm missing. Any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON payload does not match the data model.

What you showed is a JSON object that *has* a "route" object. So you need to model a data class that *has* a `RouteDetail`:

```
data class Response(
    val type: String
    val route: RouteDetails
)
```

Then you would parse the top-level object and get the route from there:

```
val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
val response = objectMapper.readValue(response, Response::class.java)
return response.route
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the [jackson-module-kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin), this error means that Jackson can't figure out how to use your constructor/"creator" (which it can't by default for Kotlin data classes)

Answer (score 0):

Observed some of the following issues with json modelling in OP.

1. `boundingBox: JsonNode` and `coursePoints: JsonNode` is JsonNode but in json it is an array,
2. `course_points` json does not contain any specific data type so assumed here as an empty array of type `Any`.
3. I assume OP need to exclude `id` from the json, so added in json but not in DTO.

I have modelled data class for the json mentioned in OP as below

```kotlin
data class BoundingBox(
  val lat: Int,
  val lng: Int
)

data class Route(
  @JsonProperty("bounding_box")
  val boundingBox: List<BoundingBox>,
  @JsonProperty("course_points")
  val coursePoints: List<Any>?,
  // val id: Int, // need to skip while reading/writing to json str
  val name: String
)

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class RouteDetails(
  val route: Route,
  val type: String
)
```

Response json:
Added additional property `"someExtraKeys": "withExtraValue",` to demonstrate that it is getting dropped while serialisation/deserialisation due to `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`

```kotlin
val response =
"""
  {
  "type": "route",
  "someExtraKeys": "withExtraValue",
  "route": {
    "id": 40307258,
    "name": "some bike route",
    "bounding_box": [
      {
        "lat": 3,
        "lng": -9
      },
      {
        "lat": 3,
        "lng": -9
      }
    ],
    "course_points": []
  }
}
""".trimIndent()
```

Client code:

```kotlin
val jacksonObjectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
jacksonObjectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
val readValue = jacksonObjectMapper.readValue(response, RouteDetails::class.java)
println(jacksonObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(readValue))    
/*
{
  "route": {
    "bounding_box": [
      {
        "lat": 3,
        "lng": -9
      },
      {
        "lat": 3,
        "lng": -9
      }
    ],
    "course_points": [],
    "name": "some bike route"
  },
  "type": "route"
}
*/
```